# ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: python

I've already installed the dependencies with `sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2` and then installing `psycopg2` with `sudo pip install psycopg2` and even with `easy_install psycopg2`. But even after all this, if I run `python3 code.py` I get

```
ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

If I run `sudo apt-get build-dep python3-psycopg2` I get

> Picking 'psycopg2' as source package instead of 'python3-psycopg2'
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 144 not upgraded.

Same with `sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2`

Please help.

Comment: Are you installing psycopg2 in your virtual env? if not... After running sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2. Create a virtual env and try installing psycopg2 in the virtual env.

Comment: @DivakarDass can you please point me to some tutorials which tell about installing psycopg2 in virtual env? I am new to python and don't know much about virtual env.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its always better to work in virtualenv and not mess up with your system

try:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 test_env
source test_env/bin/activate
pip install psycopg2
```

run python and try to import
if you insist on installing it on your systems python try:

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

Comment: Virtualenv didn't work. But `pip3 install psycopg2` works! Thanks.

Comment: if you dont have virtualenv installed do  `pip install virtualenv`
its best practice to use it for your projects

Comment: `apt-get install python3-virtualenv`

All Python 3 packages are prefixed with `python3-`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Anaconda distribution, make sure to go with: 
`conda install -c anaconda psycopg2=2.6.2`

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/psycopg2

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
# debian like
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
$ pip3 install psycopg2

# check installation
$ python3
import psycopg2
```

Comment: This is for Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: I not seem that he want for python 3 ;D

Comment: Sorry God of Python :p

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I tried 
    'sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2'
It didn't work. 
I was trying to connect to a postgres database. It turns out that I didn't have postgresql installed. Once I installed it, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `pip3 install psycopg2` made psycopg3 available for python3, while I was trying to execute my code in python 2.7 by default

so changing my call from

`python foo.py` to `python3 foo.py` helped